# Ubuntu version 18.10 JavaFX

Tags: 18.10, javafx

load the Ubuntu version 18.10 but I can not run a JavaFx program, what I can do in version 18.04. Do I have to do something extra?

Comment: I think people could use some more information here, and your grammar could be improved a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install [*JavaFX/OpenJFX 8 - Rich client application platform for Java*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=JFx&searchon=names):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```